# Flutter / Firebase RTDB Listener still active after subscription cancellled and sign out

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

After user logs in, user is taken to a new page, statefull widget, where init method listening to realtime database is started (with Provider).

```dart
  void listenForData() {
    _fooSubscription = _databaseRef
        .child('users/${_user!.uid}/bar/')
        .onValue
        .listen((event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
        _responseData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);
      } else {
        _responseData = {};
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
    _fooSubscription
        ?.onError((e) => print('This is _fooSubscription error: $e'));
  }
```

Then on sign out I try to cancel `_fooSubscription` and call sign out.

```dart
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _fooSubscription?.cancel();
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
```

However I'm still getting `DatabaseError(-3, This client does not have permission to perform this operation, )`.

So, now user is signed out, so he/she has no permission to be able to listen to data from real time database, but **why there is any listening still happening if I have canceled subscription before signing out?**

Comment: Hmm.... as far as I can see [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/48055997742faa6578687fa45b3a944af3fa9c70/packages/firebase_database/firebase_database_web/lib/src/interop/database.dart#L355-L365), cancelling the stream calls the right methods to stop getting updates from the database.

Comment: What version of firebase_database you are using? If I try to use this: Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);, I get an error. It won't allow an Object? to be a Map<String, dynamic> or Map<dynamic, dynamic>